# how to make code for update image in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, web

I want to update an image. My function is working for the text, but not with an image.

How do I call the image in database?

I think the problem is in the controller and the view. I can re-upload or update the image with the new one.

Controller:

```js
function do_upload(){
    $config = array(
        'upload_path' => './images/upload',
        'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpg|png',
        'max_size' => '2000000');
    $config['file_name'] = url_title($this->input->post('file_name'));
}

function insert(){      
    $config =array(
        'upload_path' => './images/upload',
        'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpg|png',
        'max_size' => '200000',
        );
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->do_upload('file_upload');
        $upload_data = $this->upload->data();

    $id_soal = '';
    $soal = $_POST['soal'];
    $a = $_POST['a'];
    $b = $_POST['b'];
    $c = $_POST['c'];
    $d = $_POST['d'];
    $kunci = $_POST['kunci'];
    $status = $_POST['status'];
    $file_name = $upload_data['file_name'];

    $data = array(
        'id_soal' => $id_soal,
        'soal' => $soal,
        'a' => $a,
        'b' => $b,
        'c' => $c,
        'd' => $d,
        'kunci' => $kunci,
        'status' => $status,
        'foto' =>$file_name,
        );

    $hasil = $this->soal_model->Simpan('soal', $data);

    if($hasil>=1){
        redirect('dashboard/index');
    }
}

function ($kode = 0){
    $data_soal = $this->soal_model->Ambil("where id_soal = '$kode'")->result_array();
    $this->load->model('soal_model');

    $data = array(
        'soal' => $this->soal_model->Ambil()->result_array(),
        'id_soal' => $data_soal[0]['id_soal'],
        'soal' => $data_soal[0]['soal'],
        'a' => $data_soal[0]['a'],
        'b' => $data_soal[0]['b'],
        'c' => $data_soal[0]['c'],
        'd' => $data_soal[0]['d'],
        'kunci' => $data_soal[0]['kunci'],
        'status' => $data_soal[0]['status'],
        );
    $this->load->view('admin/home/update_admin', $data);
}

function update(){
    $soal = $this->input->post('id_soal');
    $data = array(
        'id_soal' => $this->input->post('id_soal'),
        'soal' => $this->input->post('soal'),
        'a' => $this->input->post('a'),
        'b' => $this->input->post('b'),
        'c' => $this->input->post('c'),
        'd' => $this->input->post('d'),
        'kunci' => $this->input->post('kunci'),
        'status' => $this->input->post('status'),
    );

    $this->soal_model->Rubah($soal, $data);
    redirect('dashboard/index');
}
```

Model:

```js
public function Simpan($tabel, $data){
    $res = $this->db->insert($tabel, $data);
    return $res;
}

public function Rubah($soal,$data){
    $this->db->where('id_soal',$soal);
    $this->db->update('soal',$data);
}
```

View:

```html
<form role="form" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>dashboard/update" 
    method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Quest :</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="soal" id="soal"><?php echo $soal; ?>
    </textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Answer A :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" 
    name="a" id="a" value="<?php echo $a; ?>"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Answer B :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" 
    name="b" id="b" value="<?php echo $b; ?>"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Answer C :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" 
    name="c" id="c" value="<?php echo $c; ?>"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Answer D :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" 
    name="d" id="d" value="<?php echo $d; ?>"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Key</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="kunci"> 
    <option><?php echo $kunci; ?></option>
    <option>--Select--</option>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
    <option>E</option>
    </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">    
    <label>Status :</label>
    <select name="status" class="form-control">
    <option><?php echo $status; ?></option>
    <option>--Select--</option>
    <option>Tampil</option>  
    <option>Tidak</option> 
    </select> 
    </div>

    <br>

    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="id_soal" 
        name="id_soal" value="<?php echo $id_soal; ?>"/>

    <div class="form-actions">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="<?php echo base_url();?>dashboard/index">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: are you newbie in CI?

Comment: yes i am. any problem?